# BackupPC rsync failing because it is using the wrong SSH user

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, rsync

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
backuppc@somehost.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync_bpc: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
```

I have ssh key set up for root@somehost.com and it works fine, but BackupPC keeps on using backuppc@somehost.com to try to connect. This has been working for years, but broke after upgrading to BackupPC 4.

Is there any way to force the SSH user in the configs?

Answer (score 0):

:facepalm:

https://backuppc.github.io/backuppc/BackupPC.html#Rsync-Rsyncd-Configuration

From the docs

```
$Conf{RsyncSshArgs} = ['-e', '$sshPath -l root'];
```

Ssh arguments for rsync to run ssh to connect to the client. Rather than permit root ssh on the client, it is more secure to just allow ssh via a low-privileged user, and use `sudo` in `$Conf{RsyncClientPath}`.

The setting should only have two entries: "-e" and everything else; don't add additional array elements.

This setting only matters if `$Conf{XferMethod} = 'rsync'`.